# Perl Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, strict

I am trying to store my log messages in a hash depending upon message type as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %log;

opendir (DIR, '.') or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    # some code to select TAR filename in $1
    if (-e $1.'.tar') {
        push(@{$log->{$1}}, $file); /* line 12 */
    }
    else {
        $log{$1} = [];
        push(@{$log->{$1}}, $file); /* line 16 */
}
```

Now this code gives compilation error saying:

```
Global symbol "$log" requires explicit package name at at lines 12 & 16
```

where I am actually trying to use the hash "%log". What can be a possible way to get rid of this error ? Why exactly is this happening ?

I did see some explanation on context where people replied saying the variables were created in one context and were being referred in another but I feel this variable should be available inside while loop in this piece of code. This happens only when I have "use strict" and works fine otherwise.

I have started with Perl so I do not fully understand the basics! Please help me understand why this variable is not accessible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my %log;
```

defines hash `%log`, but lines 12 and 16 don't use it. Instead, you're accessing the anonymous hash referenced by the scalar `$log` which you've never declared. You have two options.

- You could continue to use an anonymous hash.

  ```
  my $log = {};   # The creation of the hash ("{}") is currently being done
                  # implicitly by "->". This is called autovivification.


  ... $log->{...} ...
  ```

  This adds a bit of a extra complexity and an unnoticeable reduction in speed.
- You could use use a hash directly.

  ```
  my %log;

  ... $log{...} ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. I did know about this scalar and non-scalar variables concept in declaration. I appreciate you brought this out!

Comment: Then for completeness: `my %log;` declares a hash, `my @log;` declares an array, and `my $log`; declares a scalar. These are three unrelated variables which can safely co-exist (readability issues aside).

Comment: this is one responsive community.. never seen this anywhere else.. or may be I was looking at wrong places.. anyway I have taken the second option you proposed.. and took note on scalars and non-scalars! thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do with `$1`, but the hash access is not a reference, so change:

```
$log->{$1}
```

to

```
$log{$1}
```

The error message you got, says: `Global symbol "$log" requires explicit package`, because `$log` variable was not defined. Remember that `%log` and `$log` are two different variables (hash vs scalar).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not being given an option to accept both replies as correct answer to my question. Don't know how to acknowledge your effort... May be if I can share some reputation points.. dont the rules here.. I just joined today!